# How can I use keypress and event.preventDefault() together for limiting characters input?

Tags: javascript, html

I have trouble figuring out what event handler should I use on this simple character limiting function. When I hit the max value, I can't delete any characters as it seems to be counted as a `keypress` event. How can I fix this?

```
var mytext = document.getElementById("mytext");

mytext.addEventListener('keypress', function (evt) {
    if (mytext.value.length >= 8) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

Here is JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/j93qU/2/

Comment: this is working fine in my system, I am able to delete the characters after I have entered max no of characters. I am using chrome in OS X. In which browser you are testing your code?

Comment: Firefox, maybe this is what's wrong. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var mytext = document.getElementById("mytext");

mytext.addEventListener('keypress', function (evt) {
    if (mytext.value.length >= 8 && (evt.keyCode != 8 || evt.keyCode != 37 || evt.keyCode != 46)) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

});
```

The `event.which` property normalizes `event.keyCode` and `event.charCode`. It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input.

Comment: For key or mouse events, this property indicates the specific key or button that was pressed. Check http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Answer (score 2):

I would just use html input maxlength attribute

```
<input type="text" maxlength="8">
```

Comment: Yes I know, but for this one, I'm trying not to use any HTML.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use HTML? I guess you are writing website right?

Answer (score 0):

*The moment people start using scripts, they forget to do the basic things!*

Use the built-in basic `maxlength` and `size` attributes.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="8" size="8" />
```

---

In your case, limit the `preventDefault()` only to characters, or allow the special characters like <kbd>Del</kbd> and <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

```
mytext.addEventListener('keypress', function (evt) {
    if (mytext.value.length >= 8 && (evt.keyCode != 8 || evt.keyCode != 37 || evt.keyCode != 46)) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

Comment: I'm trying to only use javaScript

Comment: But *why* are you trying to complicate your problem like that?